# low consuming Virtualization for Ubuntu to use Windows XP

Tags: virtualization, windows-xp

Looking for low consuming Virtualization for Ubuntu to use Windows XP. Need to open small application with Windows XP using small interface window

Trying to save computing resources, so I'm looking for something small and neat

Comment: There's no big difference as long as you avoid CPU emulation. I'd try VirtualBox.